# Integrating An Absolute Value Using Jordan's Lemma?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am working with fermion field expansions in QFT. The fields are given by

$$\psi(x)=\int d\mathbf{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_k}}[b_{k}u(k)e^{-ikx}+d_k^{\dagger}v(k)e^{ikx}]$$

I am evaluating 
$$\int d^3x d^3x' \bar{\psi(x)}\psi(x)\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x-x'}|}\bar{\psi(x')}\psi(x')$$
 which when expanded gives me 
$$\begin{multline}
\int d^3x d^3x' d\mathbf{k}d\mathbf{k'}d\mathbf{p}d\mathbf{p'}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_kE_k'E_pE_p'}} \\ [b_{k}u(k)e^{-ikx}+d_k^{\dagger}v(k)e^{ikx}][b_{k'}u(k')e^{-ik'x}+d_{k'}^{\dagger}v(k')e^{ik'x}]\times\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}[b_{p}u(p)e^{-ipx'}+d_p^{\dagger}v(p)e^{ipx'}][b_{p'}u(p')e^{-ip'x'}+d_{p'}^{\dagger}v(p')e^{ip'x'}]\end{multline}$$

This gives me integrals like the following to evaluate:

$$\int d^3x\frac{e^{i\mathbf{(k-k')x}}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}$$

I was wondering if it is possible to evaluate this integral using Jordan Lemma. Alternatively, I have evaluated it partially by computing the angular part first, that is, by writing

$$\int d^3x\frac{e^{i\mathbf{(k-k')x}}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|} = \int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{2\pi}_{0} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi}dx x^2 d\phi d\theta \frac{e^{i(k-k')x\cos{\theta}}}{|x^2+x'^{2}-xx'\cos{\alpha}|}$$

This gives me

$$\frac{\pi}{(k-k')}\int^{\infty}_{0}dx\frac{x\sin((k-k')x)}{(x^2+x'^2-2xx'\cos\alpha)^{1/2}}$$

Can I use complex variables to integrate this last integral? Because I don't know how to integrate it with usual methods. Or is there another way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is your integral $k-k'$ in the exponent instead of $x-x'$ ? And is the integration over $x$ or $x'$ ?

Comment: That is the integral. The integral is over $x$. $x'$ is just a constant, as far as the integral is concerned.

Comment: Perhaps if you told the full story (the context), we can find a better way to approach your problem, because as is the integral does not converge classically and this isn't the kind of divergence that can be fixed by contour integration.

Comment: If you could edit your post, that would be best as the comment is hard to read.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I apologize. How do I write in math mode in the comments?

Comment: It's the same format as posts, but if you are not used to it edit your post because comments do not allow you to see what you are writing before you post it. Comments also lock after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a change of variables to shift the origin to $\mathbf{x'}$:

$$\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \frac{e^{i(\mathbf{k-k'})\mathbf{x}}}{|\mathbf{x-x'}|} = e^{i(\mathbf{k-k'})\mathbf{x'}}\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \frac{e^{i(\mathbf{k-k'})\mathbf{x}}}{|\mathbf{x}|} = e^{i(\mathbf{k-k'})\mathbf{x'}} \mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right\}(\mathbf{k-k'})$$

using the $\mathcal{F}\{f(\mathbf{x})\}(\mathbf{k}) = \int d^3 \mathbf{x} f(x)e^{i\mathbf{kx}}$ convention. There are several known tricks to evaluate this Fourier transform, but the most elegant involves the property of homogeneity, [as I discuss here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360688/fourier-transform-of-1-x-as-a-tempered-distribution/3360695#3360695).

Evaluating the constant gives us the area of the unit sphere, $4\pi$, giving that

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right\}(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{4\pi}{|\mathbf{k}|^2}$$

(letting $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{-x}$ does not change this result). This means the integral evaluates to

$$\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \frac{e^{i(\mathbf{k-k'})\mathbf{x}}}{|\mathbf{x-x'}|} = \frac{4\pi e^{i(\mathbf{k-k'})\mathbf{x'}} }{|\mathbf{k-k'}|^2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think of doing this through FTs.